# Insert data in to the table and submit like a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a table with two rows and three columns.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here I need the second row table data's as a input field like a form. I need to fill them by my own and submit it. How can this be done.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your sending your form to serverside then there is no need to take hidden field. Instead give **name**   attribute to your fields. It will be available on the serverside page.

```
 <form id="FormName" action="server.php">
    <table border = "1">
<tr> 
<td> Male </td>
<td> Female </td>
<td> Total </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Submit Data" onclick="submitForm()" />
</form>    

function submitForm(){
if(false)//check for errors
{

}else{

            $('#FormName').submit();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a form

```
<form name="myform" action="xxx.php">

  //create 3 hidden fields here

</form>
```

HTML

```
<table border = "1" id="mytable">
<tr> 
<td> Male </td>
<td> Female </td>
<td> Total </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Submit Data" onclick="submitTableData()" />
```

On your button click, get the values of each td and assign it to the hidden fields and then call submit

```
function submitTableData()
{
   $('#hidden1').val('value of td1'); //$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2)').find('td:nth-child(1)').text()
   $('#hidden2').val('value of td2'); //$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2)').find('td:nth-child(2)').text()
   $('#hidden3').val('value of td3'); //$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2)').find('td:nth-child(3)').text()

   $('#myform').submit();
}
```

Comment: `'value of td1'` is kinda of misleading... Probably `$($(tr)[1]).find("td").val()` is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Male</td>
<td>Female</td>
<td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="textnamehere" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="textnamehere" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="textnamehere" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
function addForm {
if{
somecodes here if true
}else{
$('variablenamehere') .submit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cells of the second row just put some inputs:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="male"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="female"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total"></td>
</tr>
```

When submitting the form, you will have 3 additional parameters: male, female and total in your request which will contain the values.

You can go on even further and - if i understood it right - since you have only numbers, you can specify the input type as being `number` and, with a small javascript function, you can make the `total` be calculated automatically.